# Discord python bot sending exitcode, terminal retaining desired output

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
        await ctx.send(arg)
        nme = subprocess.call(["./test.sh",arg])
        await ctx.send(nme)
        await ctx.send(subprocess.call(["./test.sh",arg]))
        await ctx.send(subprocess.run(["./test.sh",arg]))
#on executing '$test test1' on discord it outputs:
test1
0
0
CompletedProcess(args=['./test.sh', 'test1'], returncode=0)
```

Above as is, is parroting the arguments and sending an exitcode (twice as I've duped myself) - 0 to discord, desired output just displayed on terminal, and pointers on what needs changing?

Apologies if this is listed somewhere, I'm sure it is but can't locate...

Comment: I have had it working correctly previously (data got wiped) and that was with call(), but was older discord.py version. run isn't working either - now discord gets: CompletedProcess(args=['./test.sh', 'argtst'], returncode=0) instead.   I want discord to show the output of that bash script (I probably could/should rewrite in bash) and terminal output doesn't really matter

Comment: edited question to reflect trying run()

Comment: Discord is getting the right output with subprocess.check_output() but its showing tabs and newlines as \t and \n respectively.